# RegExp to validate a http header value

Tags: javascript, http, header, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending a custom header to my back-end:

```
var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
oXhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", fileName);
```

But if `fileName` contains accents for example, I get:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
> 'é - December 3rd, 2015.pdf' is not a valid HTTP header field value.

I have a hard time understanding the [doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2)...

**edit:**

I realized that even though it does look like an accent, it's something different. It is the character: ́

It behaves strangely (ascii code 769), it confuses my browser console and even phpStorm. It comes *on top* of the very next character, no matter what, even when pasted (try it). The problem is that the content of this header value is a file name chosen by user from a file picker, and this file name contains this character. What would be the best approach to filter this kind of incident?

Comment: Can you check that the header value is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and not in UTF-8 or another charset?

Comment: @Tobías How do you check that? And also, why would I want this to happen? I enforce utf8 all over my application

Comment: @sebas, HTTP is not an utf-8 protocol, you need to transfer ascii or ISO-8859-1, so you need to alter the filename encoding before adding it to your request header, that's an utf8 diacritic character, it's invalid and the servers may reject your HTTP message (but here you have an error even before your message is sent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only US-ASCII should be used as is specified in [RFC7230 - 3.2.4. Field Parsing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) :

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data.

If you try some unsupported character

```
oXhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", "Φ");
```

then you get

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
'Φ' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

The key is where the spec says

> ... supporting other charsets only through use of [RFC2047] encoding.

so you need to encode the value 'Φ' like this

```
oXhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", "=?UTF-8?Q?=CE=A6?=");
```

In your case, you need to encode the `filename` before sending it, using [strutil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strutil) or some other library.

Or just remove any non printable US-ASCII char from the filename

```
filename.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]+/g, '')
```

Comment: thanks. I ended up filtering out values not complying with the format by catching the error directly, and informing the user of the problem. I will set an encoding system in the future because I do mean to accept whatever file name my users are giving me.